# Change JavaFX MenuButton Icon

Tags: javafx

Is there a simple way to change a JavaFX MenuButton arrow to a character or hide it completely?

```
MenuButton hamburgerMenu = new MenuButton("\u2630");
hamburgerMenu.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Ham"), new MenuItem("Buger"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following style to hide the arrow

```
.menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

You can also define a different SHAPE using `-fx-shape` followed by a `SVG` path.

```
.menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M 0 -3.5 v 7 l 4 -3.5 z";
}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: Accepted this answer as it does what I asked. As a follow up, I ended up just making a Label with an onMouseClicked that shows/hides a pane in a StackPane for the menu.

Answer (score -2):

## There are several ways to do this, here are four. The code is Jython with JavaFX. You can edit this code to meet your needs.

---

> First, the enum, for context.

```
public enum URLBarArrowConstants {
     //URLBarArrow Constants
     BYCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_SHAPE,
     NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE;
}
```

> Second, the css files, for context.

EG #1

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.menu-button .arrow-button .arrow {
     -fx-shape: "...";
     -fx-scale-shape: true;
     -fx-position-shape: true;
}
```

EG#2

```
/*ComboBox's Arrow is a Region.*/
.menu-button .arrow-button .arrow {
    /*Setting either of these two will do.*/
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
     -fx-opacity: 0.0;  
}

/*ComboBox's Arrow Button is a Stack Pane.*/
.menu-button .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url("..<file>.png");
}
```

---

> The method, in my main file.

```
def setCustomURLBarArrow(self, url_bar, scene, URLBarArrowConstant):
    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.shape import Shape, SVGPath, FillRule
```

### Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
if URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_SHAPE:

    #SVG Object
    previous_url_bar = SVGPath()

    #SVG Path
    previous_url_bar.setContent("...") # edit this 

    #SVG Fill Rule
    previous_url_bar.setFillRule(FillRule.NON_ZERO)

    #Set Fill -- 
    previous_url_bar.setFill(Paint.valueOf(Color.web("...").toString())) //edit here

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Set Region's Shape
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow").setShape(previous_url_bar)
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS and change the Regions SVG Shape

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS but instead, merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.BYCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:
    #Apply Stylesheet for URL Bar
    scene.getStylesheets().add(File("..<file>.css").toURI().toString()) //edit here
```

## Don't configure the ComboBox Arrow by CSS, instead, do it programmatically and merely hide the arrow by setting the transparency/opacity values and set a background.

```
elif URLBarArrowConstant == URLBarArrowConstants.NOCSS_AND_NO_SHAPE:

    from javafx.scene.paint import Paint
    from javafx.scene.layout import CornerRadii
    from javafx.scene.layout import Background, BackgroundSize, BackgroundImage, BackgroundPosition, BackgroundRepeat, BackgroundFill

    #Apply CSS Sheet
    url_bar.applyCss()

    #Grab Arrow(Region), ArrowButton(StackPane) ComboBox properties
    arrow_region = url_bar.lookup(".arrow")
    arrow_button = url_bar.lookup(".arrow-button")

    #Either Set Opacity to 0 or set background color to transparent.
    arrow_region.setOpacity(0.0)
    arrow_region.setBackground( Background( array(BackgroundFill, [BackgroundFill( Paint.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT.toString()), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)]) ) )

    #Set a Background Image for the .arrow-button StackPane.
    arrow_button.setBackground(Background( array(BackgroundImage, [BackgroundImage( Image( String(File('..<file>.png').toURI().toString()), True) , BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)] ) ) )       //if you want, edit this
```