# JavaFX MenuButton only as a Graphic or an Icon with the functionality of a MenuButton

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image: MenuButton]

I added a `MenuButton` and assigned an icon for its graphic. Whenever I hover over the graphic, the color changes from black to blue. The problem is, I don't need to precisely hover over the graphic in order to open the menu. If I were to click on any of the places marked with the red dots the options appear below.

I've looked around and managed to remove as many things as I could find using the following `CSS`:

```
#menubutton {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
#menubutton > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
#menubutton > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

But if clicking on those places stills opens the menu options, then it seems like there's still some space between the icon and the border of the button. [In this example you can see the space more clearly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572839/change-javafx-menubutton-icon)

Is there a way to either remove that space or give an icon the functionality of a `MenuButton` without the button itself?

P.S. The other icons work fine because they're by themselves and not as a graphic in a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also turn off the padding to the label within the menu button.

```
#menubutton > .arrow-button,
#menubutton > .label{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. With the label padding set to zero as well, there's no more extra space.